# What is the difference between は and のは?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-は

The following sentence means "seeing all the different foreign people was interesting."

This, according to my Japanese friends is incorrect:

> 色々な外国人を見ているは面白かった。

... and this is correct:

> 色々な外国人を見ているのは面白かった。

To me, the difference is so subtle that I can't really get a feel for how the presence of の really changes it.

Can someone provide an explanation that clarifies what makes の important in this situation?

Update: I'm actually still confused by this.
Couldn't the first example mean "Looking at the various foreigners was interesting", and the second example mean "That I was looking at the various foreigners was interesting"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, 「の」 changes the verb "to [be] see" into the [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) form "[be] seeing", which is what you found interesting. After that, 「は」 is just 「は」.

Comment: Isn't it already in the gerund just by having ている?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the gerund, nevermind.

Comment: I think that the notation “[be] seeing” is confusing because it suggests that it is a progressive form instead of a gerund.  It is probably better to just write “seeing.”

Comment: While you are probably correct, I wanted to keep the auxiliary verb in there to distinguish 「見ているの」 from 「見るの」.

Comment: A "gerund" is a verb that has been changed it into a noun that identifies the action the verb represents. "swim" -> "swimming", "look" -> "looking", etc.

Comment: English lacks the granularity to translate the 「～ている」 conjugation properly; translating it as "to be Xing" is the closest equivalent in English, but it is *not* actually the gerund.

Comment: After some time, I think I get this now. The ~ている form is all about the tense (or "aspect") of what is taking place, and the の part turns it into a noun - the thing that is being commented on.

Comment: in response to the 7th comment, i think 見ている is more of "am looking" instead of "looking"

Answer (score 10):

By putting "の", your are making a nominal group from the proposition that precedes it, and you put the focus on the action (there is a nuance with "こと", which takes practice to feel). Then, since you made a nominal group, you need your usual particles after, such as は、 に、 or whatever is required.

Examples:
ケーキを食べるのが好きです。
I like to be eating a cake. (The fun is in the eating.)

ケーキを食べることが好きです。
I like to eat cakes. (Generality. I like cakes.)

外で子供が遊んでいるのにじゃまされました。
I have been disturbed by children playing outside. (The playing is the reason of the disturbance)

Comment: One sounds like what you want to do now and the other like a description of your tastes. Is that right or that's just pure coincidence?

Answer (score 5):

we use の when we are talking about the verb.  It is like "to" or "-ing" in English.

Answer (score 5):

Actually both forms are correct. の is a recent development in Japanese, before it appeared, you'd use the 連体形(行く/熱い/綺麗な[る]/食べた[る]) directly before particles. An example can be seen here:

> 今宵は夜毎にこゝに集ひ來る骨牌（かるた）仲間も「ホテル」に宿りて、舟に殘れる***は***余一人のみなれば。
>
> 森鴎外　「舞姫」

You should still use の, though.

Comment: Nowadays, the omission of の is rather for verse i.e. writing stories, poems, etc.

Comment: @syockit, that's true, but I've noticed some contemporary people clearly omitting の when speaking(no ん no nothing). What I don't know is whether that's because of pedantry or because of their dialect. I'd say it's the former.

Comment: I don't know if it's called pedantry, but in speech, it's usually used in dramatic/empathic(emotional) sentences, like when complaining someone's behavior, or feeling sorry for a sad incident, etc.

Comment: (In modern Japanese) zero-nominalization is common in some particular constructs (see http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/zero-nominalisation-why-and-when), but not in others. Omitting の in the example sentence will definitely mark you as a non-native speaker.