# What does ～んじゃなかった do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The following [sentence](http://ziddy.japan.zdnet.com/qa7441191.html?order=DESC&by=datetime) was translated in the following ways:

> 窓を開けたままで寝るんじゃなかった。
>   I shouldn't have slept with the window open.
>   I regret (that) I was sleeping with the window open.

But why does `～んじゃなかった` make the meaning "I shouldn't have slept" rather than "I hadn't been sleeping"?

Comment: I would've thought it was a rhetorical question as in "Was it not the case that I slept with the window open?"

Comment: @Flaw Wouldn't that be ・・・寝たんじゃない？

Comment: @ジョン I suppose. Which is why it struck me as odd because I already had some form of prejudgement when reading the sentence.

Comment: The meaning is accurate as translated. But I can't answer "why" and I'm having trouble finding it in J-J dictionaries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example, your ～寝【ね】るんじゃなかった is a shortened form of ～寝【ね】ることではなかった.

～Vことだ is a common command form, and ～Vことではない is used by extension as a form of prohibition. In your example, the following transformations have occurred:

- ではない → じゃない
- こと → の → ん

In this case, the speaker is basically scolding herself because she should've known not to sleep with the window open.

Comment: The only part that does not feel very intuitive to me is こと→の.

Comment: @Flaw I would vouch for the こと→の. It's a common contraction. (hoping that contraction is the right word here)

Comment: @ジョン It's easy to see that もの→もん and の→ん. But こと→の seems to be a different thing altogether.

Comment: @Flaw Both こと and の are nominalizers, so it's not exactly fair to call it a "transformation." See http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/384 -- note that there is some disagreement on ことだ⇔のだ in the comments of the accepted answer

Comment: Though the commanding ことだ seems to be a different case than what they're discussing.

Comment: @Flaw I'm doubting myself now but is that not exactly what happens when, for eg, -ことができる becomes -のができる?

Comment: 「こと→の ... a common contraction」ということはできないと思います。「～～することだ。」「～～するんだ。」は、両方とも「～しろ」のような意味で使えますが、意味・ニュアンスが違います（「～することだ」は命令というより警告に近いと思います）し、そもそも、後悔するときに、「Ｖるんじゃなかった」は言いますが、「Ｖることではなかった」とは言いません。