# What does こと mean in this context? そとで、ものをうっていることが多いです

Tags: grammar, formal-nouns, nominalization

I'm going through [ekubo basic Japanese lessons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-Vb9MJVous&list=PLINFE8v4DOhu_3LutLwJWetAhdcCrBF4X&index=46) and there's a recurring use of the word こと I don't understand, like in this sentence:

> そとで、ものをうっている**こと**が多いです

Translated in the video as

> People usually sell something outside

My intuition would be that it is used to turn うっている into a noun (something like selling-activity)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nominalization with のが、のを](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11566/nominalization-with-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8c-%e3%81%ae%e3%82%92)

Comment: It can't be a duplicate of that question – the answers don't mention こと.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/11830)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The こと means [場合]{ばあい}, "case, circumstance, occasion, instance" (See definition #②-6-㋑ in [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/80340/meaning/m0u/)).

You can use 「～ことが多い(です)」 to mean 「～場合が多い(です)」, "It is often the case that..." "in many cases..." "often..." "tend to..." etc.

So, your example sentence can be rephrased this way:

> [外]{そと}で[物]{もの}を[売]{う}っている**こと**が[多]{おお}いです。
>   ≂ 外で物を売っている[場合]{ばあい}が多いです。
>   (lit.) Cases where (people) are selling things outside are many.
>   → It is often the case that they sell things outdoors.

Examples of ～ことが多いです:

> [子供]{こども}は、ピーマンが[嫌]{きら}いな**こと**が多いです。
>   Kids often dislike green pepper.
>   [朝夕]{あさゆう}の[電車]{でんしゃ}は、[混]{こ}んでいる**こと**が多いです。
>   Trains are often crowded in the morning and evening.
>   [不注意]{ふちゅうい}から、[事故]{じこ}が[起]{お}こる**こと**が多いです。
>   Carelessness tends to result in accidents.

Similar use of this こと:

> [価格]{かかく}は、[予告]{よこく}なく[変更]{へんこう}する**ことがあります**。
>   Prices may change without prior notice.
>   バスは**ときどき**、[遅]{おく}れる**ことがあります**。
>   Buses are sometimes late.

Answer (score 1):

It's called nominalization, and yes, it is used to turn verbs (and verb clauses into nouns).

[Verb clauses as nouns](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/verb_clauses)

> All we need to treat verb clauses as a noun is by attaching a generic noun to the clause: 「こと」（事）
>
> 「の」 can also be used as a noun replacement. The difference is 「こと」 is a more general statement while 「の」 is specific to the context of the sentence.

Further reading:

- [Nominalization with のが、のを](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11566/11830)
- [What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/11830)