# "No ga" .... -- what's this grammar rule?

Tags: grammar, nominalization

What are the grammar rules here?

> 何【なに】をする**のが**好き【すき】ですか？
>
> *Nani wo suru **no ga** suki desu ka?*

Why "no ga"? Why before "suki"? Where can I read about this?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3473/9831 / http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/9831 / http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11566/9831

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If N is a noun then `Nが好きです` means "I like N".

- 何が好きですか means  "What thing do you like?"
- の in 何をするの makes the 何をする a noun. So 何をするのが好きですか means "What thing do you like to do?"