# What is really the use of the particle "no"?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, usage, particles

So I learned that *no/の* is used as a possesive noun. For example, **Kimi no/君の** = "Your" in English. I also learned that it can be used to connect nouns together. So, say **kookoo no sensei/高校の先生**, means "high school teacher". However, I saw someone say "**Pasuta o taberu no ga suki desu/パスタを食べるのが好きです**" to mean "I like to eat pasta." So this really confuses me. From  what I know, the particle "*ga/が*"  marks the ability  of doing something, like "I can eat sushi" while "*o/を*" is used to say "I eat sushi." So the sentence "Pasuta o taberu no ga suki desu/パスタを食べるのが好きです" really confuses me. Could someone please break it down and explain it for me? (In romaji/ローマ字, as much as you can)

Comment: This の is different from the possessive の. It turns a verb phrase into a noun. You're understanding of を and が seems to be a little off. They merely mark the object and subject of a sentence respectively. Maybe this link helps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11566/nominalization-with-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8c-%e3%81%ae%e3%82%92

Comment: @user3856370 That looks like an answer to me. Why is it a comment?

Comment: @JoelRees I don't believe my comment answers the question well. The answer is in the link,