# How to express a verb acting upon another verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs

How would I express a verb acting upon another verb? For example, 'I love to dance', or 'I hate to fight!' Would you say:

```
喧嘩するを憎むよ
喧嘩してを憎むよ
喧嘩するのを憎むよ
喧嘩しを憎むよ
```

Are any of these correct? If not, how would you say it? Are there variations to choose from, or only one correct way to do it.

Comment: as per kanji damage: "戦う usually refers to an ongoing struggle rather than a single barroom punch-up." けんかする is a more common equivalent for your usage of "fight", I believe.

Comment: @yadokari Thanks, I looked it up and you're right ^^ edited accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not precisely sure what you mean by one verb "acting" on another because that could potentially means many things.  Also, it seems your examples just deal with liking/hating something, so I'll answer according to that.  In that case, the third one is correct.  You first have to nominalize the verb by adding `の` or `こと` to the dictionary form (辞書形).

> - 踊る**の**が大好きです！　→　I love to dance
> - 戦う**の**が嫌い！　→　I hate to fight
> - 映画を見る**こと**が趣味【しゅみ】です　→　Watching movies is a/my hobby

However, one verb can "act" on another with simply the `〜て` form (and possibly various, "set" endings).

> - チキンを焼いて食べる　→　I grill the chicken then eat it / I eat chicken by grilling it
> - やってみる　→　Do something and see how it turns out - `それ、やってみよう！`　→　"Let's do it" (with some uncertainty)
> - 本やペンを机の引き出しにしまっておく　→　Put away my books, pens, etc. in the desk drawer (so they'll be ready for next time)

Or different types of compound verbs

> - 着替える　→　Change your clothes ("redo your dressing")
> - 雨が降り出す　→　Begin raining
> - 仕始める　→　Start doing

So I think "a verb acting upon another verb" could really cover a lot of different situations.

---

See also [What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/78)

Comment: By act upon I meant that the verb makes a word it's object. Like in the sentence 'I threw the ball', 'threw' acted upon 'ball'. I'm sorry for the like/hate example (I should have remebered that you don't always have to use a *verb* with those). So does this apply with verbs as well? Like with 踊るのを試した, or 戦うことをやめて

Comment: @Koasamitsu Yes, your examples are fully correct, although 踊ってみた might be a more straightforward translation of "I tried to dance".