# When do I use の/こと as a nominalizer, and when do I use というの/ということ?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nominalization

I'm studying nominalizers and don't understand when to use の/こと and when to use というの/ということ.

For example, in the sentence:

> こんなによく[遅刻]{ちこく}をする**というのは**[問題]{もんだい}ですよ。

Could I say:

> こんなによく[遅刻]{ちこく}をする**のは**[問題]{もんだい}ですよ。

Is there any rule to choose の/こと or というの/ということ?

Comment: I'm no native speaker, so don't take my word for it, but I wonder, is it similar to "(Often) Coming too late is a problem." _VS_ "That you (often) come too late (that) is a problem." ?

Comment: Here is a [related question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/what-is-the-difference-between-the-nominalizers-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%81%AE).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, they are generally identical in meaning and function. However, adding という seems to add emphasis to the meaning of the preceding phrase. I do not believe there is any general rule separating the usage of the two. (As long as you're using の and こと properly, of course.)

It's hard to use Google to find sources to back this up (besides Yahoo Answers, which isn't much of a source).