# 「というのである」 basically same as 「ということである」?

Tags: nominalization

I was asked to nominalize `「傾聴」とは耳を傾けて熱心に聞く(--?--)。` These were the options:

> (1)「傾聴」とは耳を傾けて熱心に聞く`ということである`。
>   (2)「傾聴」とは耳を傾けて熱心に聞く`というのである`。

With regard to grammar, I'd think that `というのである` can be substituted for `ということである` and be grammatically correct and have the same basic meaning. I feel that `というのである` is a superset of `ということである`.

I found [When choose の/こと or というの/ということ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12590/when-choose-%E3%81%AE-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-or-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8) but the answer is not very good.

Comment: 『「傾聴」とは耳を傾けて熱心に聞くことである。』でいいのでは・・・？選択問題ですか？

Comment: To be fair, question 12590 is about comparison between ～するのは and ～するというのは rather than comparison between の and こと, and is not very relevant here. A much more relevant question is http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395. See “Cases where only こと is allowed: […] 2. When the following clause is one of だ, です, or である” in Derek Schaab’s answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not interchangeable. Only 「聞くということである」 is correct.

Firstly, the という doesn't change anything important, so it ultimately comes down to the difference between the nominalizers こと and の.

When the nominalizer immediately precedes the copula, only the nominalizer こと can be used to prevent confusion with the のだ/のである grammar. This rule applies even if the copula isn't explicitly said, as can be seen in the actual [dictionary.goo.ne.jp definition of 傾聴](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/66877/meaning/m0u/%E5%82%BE%E8%81%B4/).

Comment: If  `だ` and `である` are "copula" (I think?), then isn't `When the nominalizer immediately precedes the copula, only the nominalizer こと can be used to prevent confusion with the のだ/のである grammar. ` a self-contradiction? What is the `のだ/のである grammar.` that might cause confusion? I don't know about the grammar, but I do hear `〜なのです` and `〜なのですか` and `〜なのですよ` in conversation. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @david, good point. The の in のだ can syntactically be analyzed as a noun, but のだ is used for a specific meaning different from the "the act of -ing" meaning aimed for here, see e.g. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/what-is-the-meaning-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99

Comment: I do not see how the answer you link to states that the sentence you mark by × is wrong. I find both of them strange in writing without at least 「」 around 傾聴. More natural would be 耳を傾けて熱心に聞くの・ことを傾聴という, with a strong preference for こと to express the generality/abstractness.

Comment: @Blavius I can accept the http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/what-is-the-difference-between-the-nominalizers-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%81%AE answer because that kind of blows me away. How did that guy know that?  I gotta get real about actually studying Japanese...

Comment: Blavius, the answer is referring to the *following* verb. Judging from the examples that means the verb whose object is the nominalized clause. NOT the verb OF the nominalized clause.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm not sure how I got that mixed up. Sorry.