# Difference between であること and ということ when nominalizing a noun?

Tags: nominalization

Let's take this example from [wasabi-jpn](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/nominalizers-koto-and-no/): 田中さんが女優**であること**は言わない. What is the difference if we were to use **ということ** or even simply **ってこと** instead. Is the difference perhaps simply that it's less formal and more natural in casual speech? Would **とは** work too in this context? I guess it would be interesting to include too.

This question closely relates to [When choose の/こと or というの/ということ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12590/when-choose-%e3%81%ae-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-or-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%ae-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8) and the answer proposes that they're equivalent. Is that true?

In other words, what is the difference between these three sentences:

> 田中さんが女優**であること**は言わない
>
> 田中さんが女優**ということ**は言わない
>
> 田中さんが女優**と**は言わない

Comment: `nominalizing a noun` ← How do you nominalize a noun?

Comment: @l'électeur I guess "sentence ending with noun" would be more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two sentences can be considered as contracted versions of

- 田中さんが女優であるということは言わない,

and mean the same: *I do not disclose the fact that Ms. Tanaka is an actress.*

It is rather that である or という can be omitted in this case than であること and ということ are interchangeable.

For example, if the verb inside the clause is **not** である, obviously ということ cannot be replaced by であること while omitting という is possible.

- 私が新宿に行くということは言わない (or ...行くことは...)
- ×私が新宿に行くであることは言わない

The third sentence can mean the same as the first two, but it sounds more like a version of

- 田中さんを女優とは言わない　*I wouldn’t call Ms. Tanaka an actress (but something else)*.

---

Note that it is not always the case that という can be omitted in ということ (whose usage is rather broad). Just one example:

- 田中さんは女優だったということだ. *They say Ms. Tanaka was an actress.*
- ×田中さんは女優だったことだ.

A contraction is だったと**の**ことだ.

Comment: By that same logic, this means that when using こと as a nominalizer, we're basically omitting という from ということ?

Comment: I think  mostly yes when ということ _simply_ nominalize a sentence. E.g. 私の趣味は走ることです cannot have という inserted. 走ることは私の趣味です _can_ be 走るということは私の趣味です, but the latter sounds too strained. Also regarding 'simply': 明日雨が降るということは花火は中止だということだ - both という cannot be omitted.