# Can someone explain the use of こと in these types of sentences?

Tags: meaning

Ok, still a newbie to Japanese. I've run across the word こと more and more recently. I'm having a hard time understanding what effect it's having on the sentence. For example, although I know the meaning of all the sentences below, I can't tell you what こと means or what it's doing to the sentence. Can someone give me some insight into its meaning? Thanks. See examples below

最初は国道を走りましたが、混んでいましたので、高速道路で行く**こと**にしました。 First I took the National Road, but traffic was heavy, so we decided to take the subway.

トラックを追い越す**こと**は難しいです It’s hard to pass trucks.

静岡辺りでスピード違反でパトカーに捉まってしまいました。すごい罰金を払う**こと**になりました Around Shizuoka, we were stopped by a police car for speeding. I had to pay a huge fine.

雨が降っていましたから、地下鉄で行く**こと**にしました Because it was raining, I decided to go by subway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntactically こと is a [nominalizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization) in all these sentences, i.e. it turns a verb into a noun by simple concatenation (e.g. 行くこと, 行く modifies こと).

Semantically,

- [verb]+ことにする is a set phrase and means "to decide to [verb]"
- [verb]+ことになる is also a set phrase and means "to turn out that [verb]".

[verb]ことは難しいです just means "[verb]ing is difficult" or "it is difficult to [verb]".

---

Another nominalizer in Japanese is の. For a difference in usage see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/what-is-the-difference-between-the-nominalizers-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%81%AE).

Comment: [verb]のは難しいです:  Not to be confused with 連用形＋にくい.

Comment: Very nice job breaking it into the syntax and semantics.