# Use of ことです in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particles, verbs, nominalization

This is the example sentence: 私の趣味はギターを弾くことです。

My translation - Playing the guitar is my hobby.

However, why is it not: '私の趣味はギターを弾きます。’

Basically I don't understand this use of 'ことです'.

Comment: cf. What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/what-is-the-difference-between-the-nominalizers-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%81%AE

Comment: sentence of `弾きます` sounds like `my hobby wants/is going to play the guitar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: nominalization.

---

In this case, it's not really a quirk of the Japanese language, at least you're doing pretty much the same in English as well.

In English, we don't say

> *My hobby is play the guitar.
>
> *As for my hobby, play the guitar.

The pattern `A is B` needs two things (either a noun, or mentioning a word or phrase, as in *swim is a verb*) for A and B. So we use the gerund `playing`, which basically refers to the act of doing the action `play`.

> My hobby is playing the guitar.

This does not mean that playing the guitar is done by your hobby, `playing the guitar` is behaving like a noun here.

The same goes for Japanese. `私の趣味はギターを弾く` could perhaps mean `my hobby plays the guitar`, but what you want to say is that the *act of playing* is your hobby.

`弾く事【こと】` (こと is usually written in *kana*) is almost literally the *the act of playing*.

And `ギターを弾くこと` is `playing the guitar`, which is your hobby, ie. 趣味.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I've *ever* seen the nominalization 「こと」 written as 「事」 (aside from 変換ミス). Of course, that could just be because I don't read widely enough.

Comment: @Darius Nominalizer こと is written in kana in modern standard Japanese, but using 事 is not totally wrong. You can see them especially in older documents.

Comment: @Darius Nominalizer I only wanted to mention the kanji to show the literal meaning of the phrase. And yes, in older documents you can find many more kanji: 迄【まで】, 行き度【た】い, と雖【いえど】も, 今【いま】茲【ここ】に &c.