# Usage of の before です

Tags: grammar, nuances, particles, particle-の

For example

> この中でどれが一番難しいのですか。
>
> 数学が一番難しいのです

Is the の here used as nominalizer meaning "one" or is it used as explanatory/emphasizing のです?

I assume the sentences translate to "Amongst these (courses) which is the most difficult **one**? Math is the most difficult **one**."

Therefore I think the の here is a nominalizer, but I rememberer reading that nominalizing の cannot be used before です and we should use こと instead.
For example:

> 私の趣味は映画を見るのです。x
>
> 私の趣味は映画を見ることです。√

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/what-is-the-difference-between-the-nominalizers-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-and-%e3%81%ae)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of の devides into (1) pronoun and (2) nominalizer.

1. 難しいのと簡単なやつ、どっちがいい？ Which do you like, difficult one and easy one?
2. それが難しいのは知っている I know that it's difficult.

And, when the nominalizer appears in the position of the predecate of the sentence, we call it "explanatory/emphasizing の".

Speaking of your examples, you can regard この中でどれが一番難しいのですか and 数学が一番難しいのです as either pronoun or explanatory の.

As you say, you can't use nominalizer の in the position of the predecate unless it's explanatory/emphasizing の. In other words, の can be used before です when it's a pronoun or explanatory/emphasizing の.

- そのメガネは映画を見るのです Those glasses are one to watch movies
- 何するんですか？ → 映画を見るんです