# What is the で in the movie name 「地獄でなぜ悪い」?

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-で, titles

The English translation on Wikipedia is "What's so bad about hell?" But I'd think that sentence would use は instead of で: 「地獄**は**なぜ悪い」. So I'm confused what role で is playing.

Perhaps it's location で: "What's so bad about in hell?", or the noun+で used to connect nouns with other phrases: "It's hell, what's so bad [about that]?"

Comment: I'd read that で the same as [Why is で used in 「大英雄が無職で何が悪い」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40881)