# Translate a sentence, English to Japanese

Tags: translation

To say **We Learn by Teaching**. Would it be said as:

Watashitachiha, kyoiku de manabimasu.

I don't know if this is correct?

Comment: Search Google: http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/We+learn+by+teaching

Comment: Hi and welcome!  Learn to ask better question on this site: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The antonym for 学ぶ (manabu) is 教える (oshieru). 教育 is *education* in general, and it includes both teaching and learning. Here, we need a word that only means *teaching*.

> 私たちは教えることで学びます。
>   わたしたちはおしえることでまなびます。
>   Watashitachi wa, oshieru koto de manabimasu.

こと after 教える is a [nominalizer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/5010) (in a nutshell, it turns 'teach' into 'teaching').

Note that is grammatical but still sounds unnatural to the eyes of Japanese people. In particular, 私たち (watashitachi, "we") is not something we frequently use in Japanese sentence. To describe this idea, you can use shorter phrases like this.

> 教えることは学ぶこと。
>   Teaching is learning.

There is [a proverb using classic Japanese grammar](http://kotowaza-allguide.com/o/oshiuruwamanabu.html) that essentially says the same thing, but I think you can forget this because it's not very popular.

Comment: Kewl! Thanks for the explanation Naruto ;-)