# How to say "I like to draw this particular character"?

Tags: grammar

I would like to say "I like to draw Doraemon". Is this correct?

ドラえもんを描きますのが好きです。

Comment: ドラえもんの絵を描くことが好きです

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to say “I like to draw this particular character”?
>   I would like to say "I like to draw Doraemon". Is this correct?
>   ドラえもんを描きますのが好きです。

I find we never put ます in the objective phrase of のが好き.

You can conjugate the verb to connect to a noun; 描くの, and say ドラえもん**を描くのが好き**です。We prefer **～を（～）するのが好きです** though we prefer 描くことが好きです, and（する）ことがあります.

料理をするのが好きです。
読書をするのが好きです。
話をするのが好きです。

話すのが好きです。
読むのが好きです。
働くのが好きです。
I find these three feel overly formal with こと.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that the ます is unnecessary there. I'm not sure why I added it.

For my purposes, I wanted to say "I like to draw Doraemon" in a casual manner, so I think ドラえもんを描くのが好きです works well enough. Thanks a lot for your help and all the examples!

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you saying that  描くことが好き is preferable to 描くのが好き, but a する verb would take の?

Comment: @user3856370 Yes, we seem to prefer するのが好きだ over することが好きだ for most of the occasions. 描くのが好き or 働くのが好き is also no problem, but when it's said with です, it sounds more complete with こと as 描くことが好きです, maybe because it's short.