# などということは vs などというのは, is first one used to "physical things" and second one to "activities"?

Tags: grammar

[image]

I stumbled upon this definition in "tobira". Is my understanding correct, that の is used for "activities and abstracts" and "こと” for more physical things?

Comment: I believe it's the other way around, but that's my guess from what I know about こと。If I say 小テストがあること it means "things like having a quiz" those type of "activities"

Comment: This question may already have an answer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/what-is-the-difference-between-the-nominalizers-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%81%AE