# Question about するの

Tags: particle-の, nominalization

I translaed the first line of しろくまカフェ to:

> 笹{ささ}を 食{た}べながらのんびりするのは 最高{さいこう}だなあ
>
> Eating bamboo while relaxing is the best

But there are a couple of particles that I wasn't quite sure of. Any advice would be much appreciated.

1. **するの**: I understand that `のんびり` is a so-called "する verb", so this takes する at the end to turn it into a verb, but what role does the の particle play here? I normally undersatnd it to be the possessive (mine, his, yours etc) but does it play a different role here?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it turns the verb into a noun. In order to comment on the nature of the activity of eating bamboo while lying around, you first have to turn it into a noun phrase, and の does that here.

こと can be used to create noun phrases as well, but there are cases where they are not interchangeable.

I recommend reading the [imabi article](http://www.imabi.net/nominalization.htm) on the subject.

Comment: The author of the article seems very skilled but still cannot write あの事件のこと は よく覚えている for #8. This part seems somehow difficult, after all.

Comment: @user4092 Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, never mind. It's comment for imabi, not your answer.

Comment: ^ imabi って例文結構間違ってますね。。#36「情報**を**目を通す」も変ですし。