# Can 趣味{しゅみ} be used with a verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Can you combine 趣味{しゅみ} with a verb?

> 1. 趣味{しゅみ}はジョギングをします。
>      translation: My hobby is jogging. (verb)
> 2. 趣味{しゅみ}はジョギングです。
>      translation: My hobby is jogging. (noun)

Comment: Do you have a theory as to why sentence 1 is wrong? How about an English translation of each one? Also, could you please edit the title of your question? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question. Thanks!

Comment: I've been told that you can't combine suki with a verb, but I can't find any sources with concrete information about this. Sorry about the title, will edit now.

Comment: I still don't see how 好き fits in here. Are you wanting to say "I like jogging" rather than "my hobby is jogging"?

Comment: @mamster sorry my bad, I mixed up two different questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

趣味はジョギングをします is incorrect; it sounds like there is a person called Shumi who is jogging.

If you want to say "My hobby is ～**ing**", you need to use [a nominalizer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/5010).

> - 趣味は走ることです。  My hobby is running.
> - 趣味は本を読むことです。 My hobby is reading books.

ジョギング(する) is a suru-verb, which means the part before する works also as a noun. So you can say both of the following, although the latter is redundant and wordy:

> - 趣味はジョギングです。 My hobby is jogging.
> - 趣味はジョギングをすることです。 My hobby is jogging.