# 豊かになることが sentence construction

Tags: particle-が, nominalization

> 能力のある人や努力した人**が**豊かになること**が**本当の平等というものだろう。

why did we use が two times in this sentence, and what does the mean of 豊かになること sentences

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/9831

Answer (score 6):

> 「能力{のうりょく}のある人や努力{どりょく}した人**が**豊{ゆた}かになること**が**本当{ほんとう}の平等{びょうどう}というものだろう。」

To comprehend the reason for the double-が, you will need to analyze the sentence grammatically.

What is the grammatical subject of this sentence?  It is 「能力のある人や努力した人**が**豊かになること」.  Yes, the subject itself is a mini-sentence that is nominalized by 「こと」.

Since the subject is a nominalized mini-sentence, it just so happens that it contains a が within itself.  That is the ***first が*** in the whole sentence.

That rather long subject must now take the subject marker, which is the ***second が***.  Thus the core structure of this sentence is:

> "A が B だろう。" = "A would be B."

A (subject): 能力のある人や努力した人が豊かになること "that those who have abilities or have made efforts become wealthy/successful"

B (predicate): 本当の平等というもの "what should be called 'true equality'"

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the normalized mini sentence and why do we use it ?