# Why is こと used at the end of this kind of sentences?

Tags: particle-こと

So, often I see こと being used at the end of sentences like

> 「私の最後の希望はあなたと共に死ねることなのに」

> 「それは僕の生命を吸い取るために　僕の全身を凍らせていないことだ」

Is this like how in English you normally would say "My aim is ーーー" and you would use a verb in gerund form like "living there" (although to live there would be ok too)? So because 希望 is a noun what 希望 is should be a noun too, therefore 「死ねること」is like "My hope is *dying* with you", right?

Should the second phrase be understood as:

> それは•••全身を凍らせていないことだ
> That is... not *freezing* my whole body

Would this phrases make sense without こと?

Comment: Show us the context/sentence right before それは~

Comment: @Chocolate  The previous sentence is「ディオ　勝ったと思うな　　お前はミスを犯しているんだ。」

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is basically correct, this こと is a nominalizer, something that turns a verb into a noun. You need a noun before だ, なのに, etc.

- [What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/5010)
- Wasabi - [Nominalizers: こと and の](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/nominalizers-koto-and-no/)

But note that 死ねる is the potential form of 死ぬ. Thus 死ぬこと is "dying" but 死ねること is "being able to die". Likewise, 凍らせていない is negative -teiru form. 凍らせないこと is "not freezing" but 凍らせていないこと is "having not frozen".

> 私の最後の希望はあなたと共に死ねることなのに
> My last hope is being able to die with you, but...
>
> それは僕の生命を吸い取るために　僕の全身を凍らせていないことだ
> It is that [something/someone] has not frozen my whole body in order to absorb my life.

Comment: Is it essential to nominalize the predicate if the subject is a noun if I want to say "the (subject) is ~~~" and not "(subject) does ~~~"? Something like "My plan is to eat", "your mistake is not eating". 「私の計画は食べることだ」「あなたのミスは食べないことだ」. As I write this it's becoming more clear that it indeed makes more sense this way.

Comment: @RubenOliveira Yes, こと is used that way, and it's mandatory. 私の計画は食べる would mean "My plan eats."

Comment: What about this sentence: 「この穴は いずれは私の体も吸い込んでしまうことだろう」? I think without こと it would probably mean the same thing, but why is it there?