# What does 「問題」とはいえないことにも気づいていない mean?

Tags: reading-comprehension

> それなのに、解決策がどこかにないだろうか、と②「検索」する。検索で解決するようなものだったら、**「問題」とはいえないことにも気づいていない。**

"問題とはいえないこと" means something that can not be called issue;
ことにも気づいていない　means being unaware of something;

but when you put them together,I will be very weird and unintelligible in the context.
how to understand this sentence?

Comment: When there are footnotes or something in the text you want to quote, it would help to either include the footnote (if it matters at all) or just remove the marker (if it doesn't).

Comment: I would remove at least two of the commas from that text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This こと is not "something" but a nominalizer ([What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/5010)). And the こと nominalizes everything before it in the sentence. Don't be deceived by a comma in a relative clause.

> [検索で解決するようなものだったら、「問題」とはいえない]**こと**にも気づいていない。
>
> They haven't even noticed **(the fact) that** [you cannot call it a "problem" if it's something that resolves with a search].

In other words, the author is saying that a true "problem" refers to something that cannot be solved by an internet search.