# What’s the difference between のは and こと？

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nominalization

I have been very confused lately between these two and not knowing when to use eachI know that both nominalise a verb but that’s as far as it gets!

Comment: Don't you mean the difference between の and こと? Both can be followed by a は to mark a grammatical topic, but that's not (directly) related to the choice between the two.

Comment: yeah that’s the one I mean

Comment: This question has (unsurprisingly) [been asked before](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/what-is-the-difference-between-the-nominalizers-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-and-%e3%81%ae). (The answer given even has a few remarks about のは where the addition of は *is* relevant -- I must say I didn't think of those when I wrote my comment above.)