# When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?

Tags: grammar, verbs, て-form, aspect

Last night, when I asked my wife to send an email to me, she said もう送っている which I took to mean that she was "sending the message". (The message had a big attachment so I imagined that it could take a few minutes to be sent.) What I later realized is that in this context 送っている meant that "the message has been sent". I thought that Vている is the same as a progressive or -ing form in English. According to my wife, if she wanted to say she was sending the message it would have been, 送っているところ.

Is it true that the 送っている always means **continuation of state** (ie. "has been sent") or does it depend on the context? Other verbs in the Vている form (for example 食べている) seem to mean **continuation of action** (ie. "eating"). Does the meaning of Vている change depending on the verb it's used with? Can we divide every verb into a "continuation of state" or a "continuation of action" category or is it more complicated?

Finally, where does てある fit into all of this. From my textbook grammar, I would have thought 送ってある would be the correct phrase for "it has been sent".

Related question: [If Vて+いる isn't a gerund, then what is it?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/if-v-isnt-a-gerund-then-what-is-it)

Comment: I think you mean "When is Vている progressive and when is it perfect?" You are making a basic mistake: confusing gerund and progressive.

Comment: @sawa I'm not good with grammatical terms. :) I didn't even know what a gerund was until I looked at the other question I linked to. If perfect="continuation of action" and progressive="continuation of action" then that is what I'm trying to ask...

Comment: @user27478 - Perfect just means that the action of the verb is completed according to the internal logic of the sentence. In English, "It has been sent.", "It had been sent.", "It will have been sent." are all perfect.

Comment: For the record, I removed the incorrect use of word “gerund” (finally).  The answer by Derek Schaab to the linked question explains why it is incorrect to call the ～ている form a gerund.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The key to understanding this difference in **aspect** (not tense) lies in knowing what kind of verb we're dealing with. For verbs that describe actions (食【た】べる, 走【はし】る, etc) and events (降【ふ】る, 吹【ふ】く, etc), ～ている shows the continuation of an action. For verbs that describe changes in state (死【し】ぬ, 割【わ】れる, 溶【と】ける, etc), ～ている shows the continuation of a state.

Another way to conceptualize this is the idea that action/event verbs can take place over a length of time, while change-in-state verbs often happen instantaneously.

There are some diagrams on [page 54 of this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=l-C4H2sBJlEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q&f=false) that help a little. I will redraw two of them here (with some modifications) for the sake of convenience:

#### Type 1: action/event verbs

[image: Diagram for 食【た】べている]

#### Type 2: change-in-state verbs

[image: Diagram for 割【わ】れている]

So where does 送【おく】る fit in? We might be tempted to think that 送【おく】る is an action verb, and in a sense it is, as it is transitive and takes a direct object. But 送【おく】る shows an instantaneous change in state: a change from *not-sent* to *sent*. This is why 送【おく】っている means "I have sent [it]."

"Ah," you say, "but there are change-in-state verbs that happen over a length of time. How do we deal with those?" Let's look at 溶【と】ける:

> アイスが**溶【と】けている**よ。はやく食【た】べなさい。 Your ice cream **is melting**. Hurry up and eat it.
>
> アイスが**溶【と】けちゃう**よ。はやく食【た】べなさい。 Your ice cream **will melt away**. Hurry up and eat it.
>
> うわぁ、アイスがぜんぶ**溶【と】けている**。どうしよう？ Woah, the ice cream **has** all **melted**. What should we do?
>
> 友【とも】だちとしゃべっている間【あいだ】に、アイスが**溶【と】けちゃった**。 My ice cream **melted away** while I was chatting with a friend.

溶【と】ける is one of those pesky verbs that doesn't fit into just one of our categories above. It could be taken as either an event verb or a change-in-state verb. So 溶【と】けている could be taken as "is melting" or "has melted", depending on the context. Verbs such as 死【し】ぬ, however, show only an instantaneous change in state. 死【し】んでいる always means "has died", and not "is dying".

"But!" you say, not wishing to be denied any chance for objection, "What about using ～ている with expressions of frequency?" This is where ～ている doesn't line up with any of our nice English translations:

> 古【ふる】くなった細胞【さいぼう】は毎日【まいにち】**死【し】んでいる**。 Old cells **die** every day. (not *are dying* or *have died*)
>
> 毎週【まいしゅう】大阪【おおさか】に**行【い】っている**。 I **go** to Osaka every week. (not *am going* or *have gone*)

This could be interpreted as a use of progressive aspect, but translating it into English with an *-ing* verb form doesn't work grammatically.

### Movement verbs

Verbs like 行【い】く, 来【く】る, and 帰【かえ】る, which deal with movement from one point to another, look like action verbs on the surface, but in their ～ている forms, they work more like change-in-state verbs:

> 彼【かれ】は日本【にほん】に**行【い】っている**。 He **has gone** to Japan. (He went to Japan, and is still there.)
>
> お父【とう】さんはまだ**帰【かえ】っていない**。 Dad **hasn't come home** yet. (He may be on the way home, but the change in state from *not-home* to *home* hasn't happened yet.)

### ～ところ

There are times when you want to take a change-in-state verb and "zoom in" on the point when the change takes place to treat it like a continuous-action verb. This is what ～ところ is for:

> 送【おく】るところだ。 I am just about to send it.
>
> 送【おく】っているところだ。 I am sending it right now. (implies that the speaker has her finger on the button for "Send")
>
> 送【おく】ったところだ。 I just sent it.

Naturally, ところ can also mean "place", so you might have to do some contextual sleuthing to figure out which is meant:

> ビルが**崩壊【ほうかい】している**ところを見【み】た。 I saw the building as it **was collapsing**. (note ～ている in Japanese, *was* in English!)
>
> 道路【どうろ】の**崩壊【ほうかい】している**ところを直【なお】す。 We will repair the places where the road **has collapsed**.

～つつある, attaching to the ～ます stem (壊【こわ】れつつある), can be used like ～ところ, but is more common in writing than in speech.

### ～てある

The main difference between ～ている and ～てある (aside from the fact that ～てある requires a transitive verb, which I'm sure you already know), is that ～てある **implies the existence of an actor who performs the action for some purpose**. ～ている, on the other hand, has no such implication, and reads as though the action occurred with no particular purpose. Thus we can draw the following contrast:

> ○ 寒【さむ】いので、窓【まど】が閉【し】めてあります。 It's cold, so the window has been closed.
>
> × 寒【さむ】いので、窓【まど】が閉【し】まっています。 <strike>It's cold, so the window is closed.</strike> (incorrect)

Suppose, however, you walk into a room with an open window, and you have no idea whether the window was opened for some purpose. In this case, ～てある is incorrect:

> ○ あ、窓【まど】が開【あ】いている。 Ah, the window is open.
>
> × あ、窓【まど】が開【あ】けてある。 <strike>Ah, the window has been opened.</strike> (incorrect)

Comment: Which app you used to draw that illustrations above ?

Comment: @Derek Schaab I'm still confused with the: 寒いので、窓が閉めてあります。 -> It's cold, so the window has been closed. Why can't we just say: It's cold, so the window is closed.(it's a state of 'being closed', right?) and for the あ、窓が開いている。-> can we say, Ah, the window is being opened? instead of 'Ah the window is open.'

Comment: @Derek Schaab If I want to use a dictionary like https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6
where is the definition that implies the concept/meaning of this 'state of change verb' of て?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction being drawn between "event" and "change of state". If you had asked me before, I would have said that those mean the same thing; the way you know an event occurred ("something happened") is that some object's state changed (i.e., there was an observable effect). But it seems the distinction here is between continuous processes and instantaneous state-transitions?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question, I'd say it depends on context. The もう in your first example indicates that it's supposed to be read as a continuation of state, while the ところ in the second example indicates it's supposed to be read as a progressive.

One might also ask what the relation between 〜た, 〜ている, and 〜てある is. Here is an illustration I once read:

> 電車が来る。

The train is coming into view.

> 電車が来た。

The train has just arrived.

> 電車が来ている。

The train has arrived and passengers are boarding.

来てある is ungrammatical basically because 来る is intransitive. The 〜てある construction implies a certain agency: someone performed an action on something and it remains in that state (by some deliberate action or inaction). Drohan gives the following examples in *A handbook of Japanese grammar*:

> 戸が閉まっている。 The door is closed.
>
> 戸を閉めている。 The door is closed. They are closing the door.
>
> 戸が・戸を閉めてある。 The door has been closed (and has been left so).

Comment: "来てある is ungrammatical basically because 来る is intransitive" - but isn't 閉まる intransitive too, so how come 閉まってある is fine?

Comment: Oops, I mistyped. I'll fix that.

Comment: (Edited, due to it being a typo.) Additionally, I think using "just" in the translation for 電車が来た is a little off. There are separate grammar points which express the meaning of "just" in Japanese. 来た merely shows the action has completed, and implies nothing of when, no?

Comment: Just double checked Google, there are a few million results for "閉まってある”, for example: "本棚に閉まってある本", "本当に大切な事は閉まってある". I thought this wasn't acceptable? Every day, something I was taught about Japanese gets blown out of the water.

Comment: @phirru: True. But the illustration was meant to show which form is appropriate as the train draws into the station.

Comment: If もう is supposed to indicate a continuation of state, then what would もう食べている mean? To me, that means "Already eating" as in we already started to eat and are continuing to eat at this time.

Comment: @user27478: OK, but what about もう死んでいる? That means ‘already dead’, not ‘already dying’.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Exactly! So can we say that there are some verbs like 送る or 死ぬ where ている means continuation of state and others like 食べている where it's a continuation of action?

Comment: I think it could be both. It depends on the context (like everything else in Japanese, or, for that matter, any natural language).

Comment: @phirru That is a different verb. Your examples include the transitive verb しまう, which should not be written in kanji as 閉まう but as 仕舞う. But the verb in question is しまる, which is written as 閉まる.

Comment: I think that usage dictates that 電車が来た means it's come to view, and 電車が来る is "it will come".

Comment: @sawa: That's how it was written when I found the examples, error on the author's part?

Comment: @phirru I think it's the author's mistake.

Comment: 戸を閉めている does *not* mean "The door is closed." It can only mean "*Sby* is closing the door."

Answer (score 2):

送る is not a change-of-state verb, so 送っている means "is sending", not "has sent". So you are right, the correct form for the situation you are describing is 送ってある (or simply 送った).

That being said, are you sure she did not say もう送ってる? I sometimes hear てる as a contracted form of てある (although probably not "correct" strictly speaking), but using ている for てある sounds quite unnatural to me.

Comment: See Derek's answer, paragraph 4. Are you perhaps confusing the terminology "state change verb" with "stative verb"? Because 送る seems like it could certainly be an active state-change verb.

Comment: @jkerian, I'm not confusing the two, I'm saying that 送る is an action verb, i.e. the ている form expresses the progressive, not the perfective. But I'm losing confidence. Looking online and inquiring with other speakers, it seems some people would even use 食べている to mean "have eaten". This is not a natural use for me, but maybe I'm biased wrt. dialect and/or age group. Maybe I should ask another question about this from a diachronical/regional standpoint.

Comment: @dainichi If I want to use a dictionary like weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6 where is the definition that implies the concept/meaning of this 'state of change verb' of て and the 'has been done' aspect?