# すっごいレンジの音がしてるのが気になる。What does the second の mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, jlpt, nominalization

> すっごいレンジの音がしてる**の**が気になる。

What does the second の mean in this sentence?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1363/9831

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second の is a nominalizing の.

It turns the phrase 「すっごいレンジの音がしてる」 into a noun so the grammar 「Nが気になる」 can be used to mean "N is on one's mind" or a similar meaning.

Another example of this usage of の is:

> ゲームをする**の**が嫌いです。
>
> (I) dislike playing video games.