# なってる versus なる. Who is this sentence talking about?

Tags: grammar, tense, aspect

The younger sister is worried about dog attacks. The older sister says this:

> 「そんなに心配することないわよ。もうどっかに行っちゃっていなく**なってる**わよ。」
> There's no need to worry so much. You'll reach the point where you end up not going anywhere anymore.

I'm not at all sure about the meaning of the second sentence. With the translation I gave above I would have expected just なる rather than なってる. With なってる I feel inclined to translate it as "**I've** reached the point where **I've** ended up not going anywhere anymore. This seems less likely given the context.

So, my main problem is, is the older sister talking about what will happen to the younger sister (future tense, I'd expect なる）or is she talking about herself (already attained state, なってる)?

Due to the above confusion I'm also not sure whether もう means 'already' or 'anymore'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the context you give, my interpretation is something appears menacing—let's say dogs since you mentioned dog attacks—and the older sister says "You don't need to worry that much, because it/they is/are gone already."

The subject of the second sentence, and the agent of both verbs in that verb chain has to be the thing feared.

> もう/どっかに行っちゃって/いなくなってる/わよ
> (It/they) has/have already gone somewhere and is/are no longer here any more.

As to the question about aspect, this event has already happened, and that's why the older sister tells her younger sister that she doesn't need to worry. なる doesn't work here. なった would work, but the sentence is about how the event associated with the verb affects the current situation. Hence なっている. いなくなる is a change in state verb, see these answers:

[When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/30454)

[Usage of ている in Punctual Verbs in Japanese and the Concept of Present Perfect in English](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78871/30454)

[Is 寝る a stative or active verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57193/30454)

[If Vて+いる isn't a gerund, then what is it?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1363/30454)

Comment: Well, I've no doubt you are correct but that is a pretty weird interpretation given the context. Full context: little sister's class mate got bitten by a dog yesterday and she is worrying that the same thing might happen to her. Older sister says this sentence. Still, I suppose it is just as useless as the rest of her family's advice.

Comment: I guess my main problem was failing to see that ちゃって/いなく were the beginning and end of separate clauses. Is there some obvious way to see that this isn't all one clause with the negative, progressive form of ちゃう?

Comment: @user3856370 I get your confusion. I think て＋いな(い) may have tripped you up? I just naturally parsed いなくなる as one and semantically there didn't seem to be any other possibilities.